# Word GUI (ribbon, bars etc.) became larger

Tags: windows, microsoft-office

My friend stumbled upon a problem. Suddenly (?) their Word GUI became larger, while the rest of Office and Windows stayed the same as before. How can they reduce Word to the normal size?

[image: Comparison screenshot]

Comment: You didn't mention the office version. Maybe this will help: https://www.officetooltips.com/word_2016/tips/how_to_reduce_ribbon_size_in_word.html

Comment: Please go to Quick Access Toolbar, check whether the Touch mode is enabled.